# how to parse json file from the brazzers-сarousel?

Tags: javascript, html, json, image, carousel

i'm new to javascript and trying to import my files from json to html page with a brazzersCarousel, but all i've got is displaying one image, the other one isn't displaying OR both images displays but in a table.

**brazzers-Carousel js**

```
!function(a){
    a.fn.brazzersCarousel=function(){
        return this.addClass("brazzers-daddy").append("<div class='tmb-wrap'><div class='tmb-wrap-table'>").append("<div class='image-wrap'>").each(function(){
            var e=a(this);
            e.find("img").appendTo(e.find(".image-wrap")).each(function(){
                e.find(".tmb-wrap-table").append("<div>")})}).find(".tmb-wrap-table").bind("touchmove",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var i=e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],t=document.elementFromPoint(i.clientX,i.clientY),d=a(t).parent(".tmb-wrap-table").closest(".brazzers-daddy").find("img"),n=a(t).parent(".tmb-wrap-table").find("div");
            d.hide().eq(a(t).index()).css("display","block"),n.removeClass("active"),a(t).addClass("active")}).find("div").hover(function(){
                var e=a(this).parent(".tmb-wrap-table").closest(".brazzers-daddy").find("img"),i=a(this).parent(".tmb-wrap-table").find("div");
                e.hide().eq(a(this).index()).css("display","block"),i.removeClass("active"),a(this).addClass("active")}).parent().find(":first").addClass("active")}}(jQuery);
```

**my html, js & brazzers carousel css code**

```
<head>    
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--Brazzers Carousel css code!-->
     .brazzers-daddy:after {content: ""; display: table; clear: both;}
    .brazzers-daddy {position: relative;}
    .brazzers-daddy img {width: 100%; position: relative; display: none; top: 0; left: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;}
    .brazzers-daddy img:first-child {display: block;}
    .tmb-wrap {position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    .tmb-wrap .tmb-wrap-table {display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
    .tmb-wrap-table div {display: table-cell;transition: all .3s ease; border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; padding-top: 10px; -webkit-transition: all .25s ease; -o-transition: all .25s ease; transition: all .25s ease;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="thumb-item">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src='jQuery.Brazzers-Carousel.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("photo.json", function (data) {
            var urldata = [];
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    urldata.push(value);       // Push values in the array.
                    $(".image-wrap").append("<img src='"+value.photo1+"'/ >")
                    $(".image-wrap").append("<img src='"+value.photo2+"'/ >")

                });

        });
    });
    $(".thumb-item").brazzersCarousel();

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: please provide your html code or a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i've edited a question and added the code

Comment: Why did you remove the details of the json file? My answer was based on that detail and if the json is different that could be the reason it didnt work

Comment: Why did you remove the json? your question is still leaking information.

Comment: i removed it because of stuck overflow's restrictions on the amount of code. json file's code is:
[
    {
        'photo1': '123_1.png'
    },
    {
        'photo2': '123_2.png'
    }
]

Comment: It's pretty essential part of the question (whereas the code for brazzer carousel is not! we can go and look at their code in github, not that we would need to the docs are sufficient). Your json having different key names in an array is what makes this not make sense. why cant they both be just `photo` if you control the json? All in all a [mcve] will help you get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is all a little bit backwards, you need to append your `img` tags to your html and then call `brazzersCarousel()` - not create the carousel and then try to append the images to it.

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("photo.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $(".thumb-item").append("<img src='"+value.photo1+"'/ >")
        });
        $(".thumb-item").brazzersCarousel();
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunatelly, it didn't work, now nothing is displayed

Comment: he is right though, please see this https://jsfiddle.net/nm04zxor/ js fiddle for a working example. you need to initialize the carousel AFTER you load your data from the backend. in my fiddle i used your original json.

Comment: yeah, you're right! it's working!! i just hadn't change an ".image-wrap" to the ".thumb-item" last time. thank you very mch!!! :)